# Checking If data from A column exists in B column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, exists

Basically this is what I have :

```
insert into A values(1689, 1709);
insert into A values(1709, 1689);
insert into A values(1782, 1709);
insert into A values(1911, 1247);
insert into A values(1247, 1468);
insert into A values(1641, 1468);
insert into A values(1316, 1304);
insert into A values(1501, 1934);
insert into A values(1934, 1501);
insert into A values(1025, 1101);
```

As you can see, there are 2 values to work with here. Let's call them a and b (a,b).

What I need to create is a query with condition that b must not exist in `column1`.

I'm kinda new to this, so among many things I try this looked like the closest answer but it doesn't do the job.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    A as a
LEFT JOIN 
    B AS b ON b.column = a.column
WHERE 
    B.column IS NULL
```

Comment: are both values stored in the same table?

Comment: Yeah,as u can se from the inserting data in to table.Both values are in table A

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: SQL server management studio 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, one option is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select col2
from A A1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from A A2
  where A1.col2 = A2.col1
)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22b11/1)

This will return all `col2` records that do no exist in `col1`.

Comment: THIS IS IT! Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM A WHERE
COL1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original query has the right idea, the names just don't match your description.

```
select  a1.*
from    A a1
left join A a2
    on  a2.b = a1.a
where a2.b is null;
```